# What does a checkmark in the Monster List mean?

Tags: super-mario-rpg-2023

When looking at the Monster List, what does it mean when a monster has a green checkmark next to them?

[image: Monster list showing tfour green checkmarks]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A green checkmark means you have the Thought Peak info for that monster unlocked.

[image: Thought Peak for Goomba]

These entries are typically unlocked by using Mallow's Thought Peak ability. Alternatively, you can [buy random entries from an NPC at Booster Pass](https://old.reddit.com/r/MarioRPG/comments/1800jau/for_thought_peek_completionists_good_news/) for 3 Frog Coins.